# How to fix 'ReactNative:Cannot run program' error

Tags: react-native

I created a fresh new react native project, when i run the command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I got this message:

> yarn run v1.16.0
>
> $ react-native run-android
>
> info JS server already running.
>
> info Installing the app...
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> > *:ReactNative:Cannot run program "./node_modules/.bin/react-native" (in directory "C:\Users\yelha\Desktop\rn_project_60\android.."):
> >     CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
> :ReactNative:Automatic import of native modules failed.*
>
> Configure project :app
>
> > *:ReactNative:Cannot run program "./node_modules/.bin/react-native" (in directory "C:\Users\yelha\Desktop\rn_project_60\android.."):
> >     CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
> :ReactNative:Automatic import of native modules failed.*
>
> Task :app:installDebug
>
> 10:19:24 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>
> 10:19:24 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on '5200127cb85a7465' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>
> 10:19:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
>
> Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-A520F - 8.0.0' for app:debug
>
> 10:19:24 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device '5200127cb85a7465'
>
> 10:19:24 D/Device: Uploading file onto device '5200127cb85a7465'
>
> 10:19:24 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\yelha\Desktop\rn_project_60\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
>
> 10:19:26 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>
> 10:20:11 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '5200127cb85a7465' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>
> 10:20:11 V/ddms: execute: returning
>
> 10:20:11 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>
> 10:20:11 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on '5200127cb85a7465' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>
> 10:20:11 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installed on 1 device.
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 2s
>   28 actionable tasks: 28 executed
>   info Connecting to the development server...
>   info Starting the app on "5200127cb85a7465"...
>   Starting: Intent { cmp=com.rn_project_60/.MainActivity }
>   Done in 136.52s.

i use versions:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.0

Comment: I also got same issue so, I uninstall the react native version 0.60 and try to install previous version but now it will not even install the react-native

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced same issue.
Here's the solution:

1. Open another command-line window
2. Change directory to your React-Native project
3. Key-in: `react-native start`

Keep your app open while doing these, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, it's due to `react-native` update to `0.60.0`, so init like `react-native init reactProject` have some problems.
You can run: `react-native init reactProject --version 0.59.9`

Answer (score 1):

You must run: `react-native init "nameOfProject" --version 0.59.9`