# React-Native The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, react-native

trying to run my first React-Native project but facing this error :
`:ReactNative:Cannot run program "./node_modules/.bin/react-native" (in directory "C:\Users\abdul\AwesomeProject\android\.."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
:ReactNative:Automatic import of native modules failed.`

Duplicate disclaimer : i read another question with the same title, 
That question has a successful build result but in my case Build was not successful plus the accepted answer didn't work for me

OS:Windows 10.

yarn is used .

Android Studio:Exist with last SDK.

Setup: performed following [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

so what is the wrong i did?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 'ReactNative:Cannot run program' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878393/how-to-fix-reactnativecannot-run-program-error)

Answer (score 0):

Navigated into the project directory, try deleting node_modules and yarn.lock and re-running `yarn install`.

Comment: Tried deleting and re running yarn install. Nit worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by:

- Uninstalled global react-native-cli
- Created new project with npx react-native init MyApp
- Started JS server with npx react-native start
- Run in android emulator with npx react-native run-android

And it worked!